# Redux saga call errors when firebase functions directly

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux-saga

I'm getting some strange behaviour when using redux sagas and firebase, and I was just wondering if anyone knows why this occurs.

```
yield call(firebase.auth().signOut);
```

Produces the following error:

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.i.then')]

However the following works without issue:

```
yield call(()=> firebase.auth().signOut());
```

These seem identical to me and I would like to know whats going on that causes different behaviour between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use your first version you invoke `signOut` method with incorrect context. This method is not a pure function, it depends on context `this` being specific object. You lose this context when you reference function like

```
firebase.auth().signOut
```

You could fix the problem like you did, or like this too:

```
yield call([firebase.auth(), 'signOut']);
```

In both cases `signOut` will be called like a method of the object and will not be detached from this object, so it doesn't lose context and `this` inside still points to correct instance (of the `auth` object).

This is an important concept to read and understand. Check this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: so basically the firebase call is using `this` internally to refer to its own state (which makes complete sense) but redux saga is for some reason replacing that with its own context. Is there a reason why it would legitimately want to do this for an arbitrary call like this?

Comment: Not exactly. It has nothing to do with redux saga or redux. This is how javascript works. Say, you have object `const auth = { loggedIn: true, signOut () { this.loggedIn = false }}`. If you call `auth.signOut()` it will work fine. But it won't if you do `const signOut = auth.signOut; signOut()`, because this way `signOut` is no longer connected to `auth` and `this.loggedIn` inside `signOut` doesn't reference to `auth::signedIn` property. The same happens in your case. Saga calls `firebase.auth().signOut` as if it was a pure function without context (auth), but `signOut` needs this contexts.

Comment: Oh wow i never realized that the context was disconnected on assignment like that.